# Pyomo - GLPK - Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, glpk, pyomo

I've installed Pyomo (v 4.4.1) and GLPK for Windows (v 4.55). I've added the directory for the `glpsol.exe` to the PATH variable and I can use the command `glpsol --help` successfully from any directory in the command prompt. According to [Pyomo's blog](http://www.pyomo.org/blog/2015/8/24/checking-glpk-installation), this should indicate a successful installation of GLPK as far as Pyomo's concerned. However, when I try the following example:

```
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
opt = SolverFactory("glpk")
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:pyomo.opt:Failed to create solver with name 'glpk':
The asl solver plugin was not registered as a valid solver plugin - cannot construct solver plugin with IO mode=nl

ERROR: "[base]\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", 200, __solver_call__
Failed to create solver with name 'glpk':
```

The `glpsol.exe` file is located in `C:\glpk` and has been added to the PATH variable.

I cannot seem to get this going and any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you really just using these two lines and obtain this error?

Comment: Yes...it's part of a larger example, but what I've given is recreatable on my machine.

Comment: Just to be clear: python called on a file just consisting of these two lines give that error?

Comment: Yep, paste those two lines into Spyder, Jupyter NB, etc. run it, and that's what it gives me.

Comment: Well... can't solve your problem, but it has nothing to do with glpk's exe or path-settings. It's breaking earlier! Maybe your pyomo-install is broken, maybe you will need to import the general pyomo-environment additionaly, i don't know. (I'm also surprised, that pyomo want's to connect to glkp through .nl somehow which should not work!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `import pyomo.environ` before you call the `SolverFactory`.

Comment: Gabe, you are the freaking man! That worked! Where in the documentation can I look for this?

Comment: @RyanErwin It's part of **every** example. (But yeah, the docs are, well... sparse)

Comment: It is not very well documented, and it's more an artifact of how Pyomo used to be split across multiple repositories. I'm hoping we can get around to a reorganization of the solver interfaces in the near future because this behavior is not very intuitive, IMO.

Comment: I've update the error message that is generated when the pyomo.environ package is not imported.