# PYOMO: how to create a solver with glpk

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo, glpk

I try to create a solver for a MILP-problem using PYOMO and glpk. I try

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

opt = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk')
```

just as described in the [PYOMO documentation](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/solving_pyomo_models.html).

However, this just gets me a warning:

```
WARNING: Failed to create solver with name 'glpk': Command
    '['C:\\Users\\andre\\anaconda3\\Library\\bin\\glpsol.exe', '--version']'
    timed out after 1 seconds
```

I have both PYOMO and glpk installed using `conda install`

And I can call `glpsol` from the command line - which should indicate everything is alright (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40184127/pyomo-glpk-error?rq=1)).

**Versions**:

glpk: 5.0

pyomo: 6.0.1

python: 3.8.5

windows: windows 10 pro 21H1

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Have you completely logged out and/or restarted the computer since installing everything?  Sometimes that is needed based on terminal behavior.

Comment: thanks for the tipp, I have just tried, but unfortunately the same warning appears - but I think I have found a solution (Edit ahead)

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:**

I have found something similar in the pyomo github [issue 2102](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/2102). I have adopted the mentioned monkey-patch approach and it actually worked:

```
import subprocess

def patched_subprocess_run(*args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get("timeout") is not None:
        kwargs["timeout"] = 5
    return orig_subprocess_run(*args, **kwargs)

orig_subprocess_run = subprocess.run
subprocess.run = patched_subprocess_run

# Your Pyomo call here.
```

So setting the timeout to 5 seconds works for me.